# Rsync slow over internet

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, rsync, raspbian

Rsync took over 10 hours today to transfer a 1GB file over the internet (from one Raspberry Pi to another. Are there any ways to speed this up?

Comment: get faster internet...?

Comment: Where are the devices located? Are they connected by Ethernet or WiFi? How fast is your network or internet connection supposed to be?

Comment: They are about 4 miles away from each other, one is at my girlfriend's apt and one is at mine. We both have TWC connections capped at ~30Mbps. One Pi is using Ethernet, the other is using Wifi. I think the bottleneck is still the internet, rather than the interface, do you disagree?

Comment: It could be the wifi connection. What type of connection is it, a/b/g/n/ac?

Answer (score 4):

rsync uses ssh to transfer files. Therefore what you want to do is speed up ssh. You can do that by changing the encryption method to a faster one such as arcfour or blowfish. You can do this by using the -e flag. For example

```
rsync -avt -e "ssh -c blowfish" user@dest:/remote/path /local/path
```

Personally I use blowfish but [here](http://blog.famzah.net/2010/06/11/openssh-ciphers-performance-benchmark/) is a benchmark I found real quick. Keep in mind this isn't going to make rsync super fast all of a sudden, but it could help if the bottleneck is the CPU on either side which is likely with embedded machines. Also keep in mind that your build of ssh might not have all the ciphers you see used elsewhere.

Comment: My script runs the following, how to I rewrite it to include "-c blowfish"?
rsync -rvP --remove-source-files --rsync-path="sudo rsync" pi:files/ .local >> /home/pi/run.log;

Comment: rsync -rvP -e "ssh -c blowfish" --remove-source-files --rsync-path="sudo rsync" pi:files/ .local >> /home/pi/run.log